# How to avoid conflit between MenuItemImage & MenuItemSprite in Cocos2d-x 3.15.1

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, game-engine

First I'll explain what I want to do before seeing the code, the user can click to the **PLAY** Button and after click, a popup **Menu** is displayed, the **Menu** contain 2 **MenuItemSprite** for play with bot or friend, for the **MenuItemImage** it's to display a small **background** around 2 **MenuItemSprite**.

The problem is when I want to click on a MenuItemSprite inside the Menu, nothing is happening, but when I **set** enable the Background to **false** all is okay without any problem, But I don't want this solution because I have inside **another background** (almost transparent). If the user click to this background, he can **hide** automatically the **Menu**, so I said set enable the background to false it'll give another problem **conflit** between Background (Window) and background (Menu).

Code :

```
//Background (Scene)
    background=Sprite::create(BACKGROUND);
        background->setPosition(SonarCocosHelper::UI::GetScreenCenter());
        background->setOpacity(0);
        this->addChild(background,1);

     //Background Menu
        MenuItemImage * overlayWindowItem=MenuItemImage::create(GAME_OVER_WINDOW,GAME_OVER_WINDOW,GAME_OVER_WINDOW,NULL);
        //overlayWindowItem->setEnabled(false);

        //FRIEND ITEM
        MenuItemSprite * friendItem=MenuItemSprite::create(Sprite::create(FRIEND_BUTTON), Sprite::create(FRIEND_BUTTON),CC_CALLBACK_1(MenuScene::goToPlay,this));
        friendItem->setTag(PLAY_WITH_FRIEND);
        friendItem->setPosition(Vec2(-overlayWindowItem->getContentSize().width/4,friendItem->getPositionY()));

        //BOT ITEM
        MenuItemSprite * botItem=MenuItemSprite::create(Sprite::create(BOT_BUTTON), Sprite::create(BOT_BUTTON),CC_CALLBACK_1(MenuScene::goToPlay,this));
        botItem->setTag(PLAY_WITH_BOT);
        botItem->setPosition(Vec2(overlayWindowItem->getContentSize().width/4,botItem->getPositionY()));

//menu
 menu=Menu::create(overlayWindowItem,friendItem,botItem,NULL);
    menu->setPosition(Vec2(SonarCocosHelper::UI::GetScreenCenter().x,SonarCocosHelper::UI::GetScreenCenter().y+screenSize.height));
    this->addChild(menu,1);
```

How I can avoid conflit between MenuItemImage & MenuItemSprite, I want to click on MenuItemSprite, MenuItemImage is just a background.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in your code, why are you taking overlayWindowItem as MenuItemImage? You are not calling any function (Set to NULL in your code).
Simply take GAME_OVER_WINDOW as an sprite. Please correct me if I am telling anything wrong.

Comment: I took the overlayWindowItem as a background of the menu, it take the animation automatically, but to avoid this problem I replaced the MenuItemImage with a Sprite and I repeated the same animation of the Menu for this sprite with runAction.